# Reading text files using Scanner and "No Line Found"

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use the Java Scanner class to read a text file all the way through and section each of the strings into the respected datatype such as a string "123" into long number = 123.

Here is my code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchElementException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    String filelocation = "file.txt";//this is for file path 

    ProductList p = new ProductList();
    try {
        File myObj = new File(filelocation);
        Scanner src = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (src.hasNextLine()) {
            long id = Long.parseLong(src.nextLine());
            String data = src.nextLine();
            double op = Double.parseDouble(src.nextLine());
            double cp = Double.parseDouble(src.nextLine());
            String space = src.nextLine(); //without this line I get an error input ""
             System.out.println(id +"\n"+ data +"\n"+ op +"\n"+ cp+"\n" + space);
        }
        src.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the content in the text file:

```
121 
Dining Table
129.99
119.99

1007
Leather Storage Ottoman
199.99
199.99

264
Gas-Powered Chainsaw
249.99
189.99

763
Protected Cruiser Takasago, 1898, 1/350, resin model kit
239.99
199.99

7465
Vacuum Cleaner, Green, 2252
99.99
89.99

354
Alienware 55 OLED Gaming Monitor - AW5520QF
4049.99
3039.99
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I do not understand why it is not printing the last item and how to take care of the error no line found. I understand you can throw an exception for illegals but I try that and still get the error.

Comment: It's expecting an empty line at the end of the file. You may want to check with `hasNextLine()` before reading those empty lines into `space`.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to assign that empty line to `space`. You can simply do `src.nextLine();` and ignore its result.

Comment: Or just use `Files.lines(...)`, because you're not using any of the `Scanner` features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of file, an empty line is missing. In fact, it throws an exception when tries to read the last space at line `String space = src.nextLine();`.

You can fix checking if the last space exists.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchElementException, FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    String filelocation = "file.txt";//this is for file path 

    ProductList p = new ProductList();
    try {
        File myObj = new File(filelocation);
        Scanner src = new Scanner(myObj);
        while (src.hasNextLine()) {
            long id = Long.parseLong(src.nextLine());
            String data = src.nextLine();
            double op = Double.parseDouble(src.nextLine());
            double cp = Double.parseDouble(src.nextLine());
            if (src.hasNextLine()) {
                src.nextLine(); //read the space just if exists and it is not necessary to put it in a variable
            }
            System.out.println(id + "\n" + data + "\n" + op + "\n" + cp + "\n");
        }
        src.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070970/reading-text-files-using-scanner-and-no-line-found#comment130780052_74070970) (by [Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca)):

> It's expecting an empty line at the end of the file.

Therefore I believe it is better to read the file one line at a time, in a loop, and process each line in the loop body.

I also recommend using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) as well as [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

According to the code in your question, it appears that the only thing you do with the data, that you read from the file, is to print it.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ReadText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            int count = 0;
            while (line != null) {
                count++;
                int ndx = count % 5;
                switch (ndx) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        long id = Long.parseLong(line.trim());
                        System.out.println(id);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        String data = line;
                        System.out.println(data);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        double op = Double.parseDouble(line);
                        System.out.println(op);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        double cp = Double.parseDouble(line);
                        System.out.println(cp);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // Should never get here!
                        throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled: " + ndx);
                }
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that method `trim()` is due to the fact that there is a single space after 121 in the first line of the text file content (which I copied from your question).